# ASP.Net Core изменить текущий principal при AD аутентификации

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Используется ASP.Net Core и AD аутентификация.
Нужно каким-то способом изменить текущий principal , что что у нас находится в HttpContext.User. 
Нужно вылогинить текущего юзера, пришедшего нам с АД и залогинить своего с базы.

UPD
Пытаюсь это сделать в ЕкшнФильтре и сделать его глобальным. Но сайнИн не происходит (да и наверное это и логично, так как мы работаем с АД).

```
public class UserValidationHandler : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Fiedlds
    private readonly IDataAuthorizationService _dataAuthorizationService;
    private readonly ILogger<OperationUserAuthorizationHandler> _logger;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signinManager;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public UserValidationHandler(
        IDataAuthorizationService dataAuthorizationService,
        ILogger<OperationUserAuthorizationHandler> logger,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signinManager
        )
    {
        _dataAuthorizationService = dataAuthorizationService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    #endregion

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        _signinManager.SignOutAsync();
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача была решена с исполозованием ClaimsTransformer 
http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity

Answer (score 0):

1)Что бы разлогинится нужно

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

2)Что бы залогинится, выполнить:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newUserName, false);
```

Если [1]+[2] работать не будет (при этих операциях идёт смена cookie) - то нужно сделать [1], потом редирект на другую страницу и за тем [2].

Comment: Аутентификация приходит через Cookie, текущий пользователь хранится в FormsAuthentication независимо от того откуда он пришёл с AD, с FormLogin формы, или вручную с помощью SetAuthCookie.

Comment: куки никакой не создается, у обьекта Session нет метода Abandon(), вы точно это соетуете для ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Я пользовался **Abadon** в NET2.0, у меня реализована и работает так кнопка signout. Может библиотека не та.. `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();` Возможно вместо Abadon подойдёт Clear.

Comment: Подключите в проэкт библиотеки: System.Web, System.Web.Extentions (в раздел References и в секцию assemblies web.config)